# Excel VBA, for loop ignore hidden rows

Tags: vba, excel

basically what this does is it checks each row in ws2 where a column = "Update" then pulls a particular column data and throws it in the corresponding cell in ws1. the first time this was implemented, everything was running smoothly, now for some reason it's taking a bit of time to finish.

```
Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, DestRow As Long, DestLast As Long
Dim checkstatus As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set ws2 = Sheets("TempHRI")

LastRow = ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DestLast = ws1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 2 To LastRow 'Assumes first row has headers
checkstatus = CStr(ws2.Range("AB" & CurRow).Value)

If checkstatus = "UPDATE" Then
'Column that looks up the word "Update" in ws2
If Not ws1.Range("E15:E" & DestLast).Find(ws2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        DestRow = ws1.Range("E15:E" & DestLast).Find(ws2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    End If

    ws1.Range("I" & DestRow).Value = ws2.Range("F" & CurRow).Value 'assumes supervisor is in column C in both sheets

End If

Next CurRow
```

i want to place a filter in ws1 that way i can minimize the count of rows it needs to check. now i'm pretty sure that the code below WILL NOT IGNORE hidden rows. i need help in adjusting the code to exclude hidden rows when i run the loop.

Comment: Simply use Autofilter on Worksheet2 as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) and then loop through only that range

Answer (score 3):

Try checking for the `.EntireRow.Hidden` property:

```
For CurRow = 2 To LastRow 'Assumes first row has headers
    ' DO something only if the row is NOT hidden
    If ws1.Rows(CurRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        checkstatus = CStr(ws2.Range("AB" & CurRow).Value)

        If checkstatus = "UPDATE" Then
        'Column that looks up the word "Update" in ws2
        If Not ws1.Range("E15:E" & DestLast).Find(ws2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                DestRow = ws1.Range("E15:E" & DestLast).Find(ws2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
            End If

            ws1.Range("I" & DestRow).Value = ws2.Range("F" & CurRow).Value 'assumes supervisor is in column C in both sheets

        End If
    End If
Next CurRow
```

Edit: added after comment below for `ws2`

```
For CurRow = 2 To LastRow 'Assumes first row has headers
    ' DO something only if the row is NOT hidden
    If ws1.Rows(CurRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        ' Checking ws2 as well, for hidden rows
        If ws2.Range("AB" & CurRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            checkstatus = CStr(ws2.Range("AB" & CurRow).Value)

            If checkstatus = "UPDATE" Then
            'Column that looks up the word "Update" in ws2
            If Not ws1.Range("E15:E" & DestLast).Find(ws2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                    DestRow = ws1.Range("E15:E" & DestLast).Find(ws2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
                End If

                ws1.Range("I" & DestRow).Value = ws2.Range("F" & CurRow).Value 'assumes supervisor is in column C in both sheets

            End If
        End If
    End If
Next CurRow
```

Please try the above and see if it meets your needs

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. can we also do a check for ws2 for hidden rows? thanks.